# MySQL query, syntax error i cannot locate

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

```
mysql_query(), query = CREATE TABLE hhh ( Bdate DATE, 6 INT(11) DEFAULT (3) )
```

the 6 is the name of the column, not a value.

Comment: 6 is a really bad column name. Why not use `six` instead?

Comment: You really want to create a column named `6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE hhh (
`Bdate` DATE,
`6` INT(11) DEFAULT 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in apostrophes (or backticks) to see if that helps.

```
mysql_query(), query = CREATE TABLE hhh ( Bdate DATE, `6` INT(11) DEFAULT 3 )
```

Comment: @delphist: I thought I'd amended that as well.  Good spot.  Will update my answer.